# Fullcalendar: Resize height on window resize (aka shrink while preserving aspect ratio)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I have been completely unable to resize the height of an FC (fullcalendar). I am trying to fit a FC in a div and would like the FC to fill the div completely but not go outside of it. While initializing the calendars the height attribute seems to have no effect. However the width of the FC seems to fit that of its parent div and furthermore, it resizes accordingly. But the FC's height does not. This creates a long and narrow FC that is no longer readable. How can I make the FC resize while conserving its aspect ratio so that it doesn't become unreadable?
Thanks in advance

P.S:
Just to be clear I have read the docs and tried setting the FC's height dynamically using JQuery (as well as through css) but this has not worked and I don't understand why.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //----------SCHEDULE INITs----------
  $('#schedule_1').fullCalendar({
    theme: false,
    // contentHeight: $('#scheduleDiv').height(),
    contentHeight: "auto",
    //height: "auto",
    defaultDate: '2000-01-03',
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    columnFormat: 'dddd',
    allDaySlot: false,
    minTime: "07:00:00",
    maxTime: "21:00:00",
    navLinks: false,
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true,
    header: false
  });


  $('#schedule_1').fullCalendar('option', 'height', 100); //Seems to have no effect...
});
```

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #FCFDFE;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.5.1/fullcalendar.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.5.1/fullcalendar.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="main">

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div id="schedule_1"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Second Column!</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Provide snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your specific issue with height: You're trying to set the height of the entire calendar to be less than the automatically computed height of the calendar's content. This is logically impossible.

If you set the contentHeight option to the same value (or less) as well, then it will shrink the height as you want, as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //----------SCHEDULE INITs----------
  $('#schedule_1').fullCalendar({
    theme: false,
    defaultDate: '2000-01-03',
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    columnFormat: 'dddd',
    allDaySlot: false,
    minTime: "07:00:00",
    maxTime: "21:00:00",
    navLinks: false,
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true,
    header: false,
    height: 100,
    contentHeight: 100
  });


  //$('#schedule_1').fullCalendar('option', 'height', 100); //Seems to have no effect...
});
```

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #FCFDFE;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.5.1/fullcalendar.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.5.1/fullcalendar.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="main">

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div id="schedule_1"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Second Column!</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/contentHeight/

As for the rest of your description, I'm not 100% sure what you're expecting. You asked "How can I make the FC resize while conserving its aspect ratio so that it doesn't become unreadable?" In what circumstances, precisely? If the width becomes very narrow, then even if the height shrunk accordingly (bear in mind it will never shrink below either the height necessary to display the content without scrollbars, unless that goes beyond the height of the viewport), or the exact height which you can specify), it would, at a certain point, become unreadable anyway. You can always control the perspective using the `aspectRatio` option, rather than setting an explicit height. If you perhaps clarify with a screenshot of the problem you're experiencing, and the exact circumstances it occurs, and another screenshot / mockup of how you'd want it to look, that might clarify enough to be able to suggest something more definite.

Comment: But this calendar has no content, right? I understand content as events.

Comment: Changing the contentheight just adds a scrollbar and doesn't respect aspect ratio. How can basically miniaturize the schedule?

Comment: the "content" as far as fullCalendar is concerned is the grid on which the events are placed, no matter whether any events are placed yet. As for "miniaturising", as I said in the answer it'll help if you give an idea of what you actually mean. Once you shrink it beyond a certain point it'll be unreadable. fullCalendar doesn't really have a "mobile device" mode, if that's what you're after. If you want the amount of content to be smaller, you can set `height: "auto"` and change `slotDuration` to a bigger value (as suits you), this will make the content height physically shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Its due to the contentHeight set to "auto".

```
$('#schedule_1').fullCalendar('option', 'height', 100); //Seems to have no effect...
```

So it doesnot reflect back the code your trying to set in the above line.

For your refference I have given link below:
https://jsfiddle.net/4cpn5b5v/

Comment: This just creates a scroll bar though. I'd like the calendar to shrink vertically and not have a scroll bar.

Comment: You can control your scroll bar using CSS change as below:
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
It would help your issue fix.